# Flex ModuleLoader component causing memory leak. How can I unload Modules properly?

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, flex3, flex4

The application is too big to describe here, but I can tell you I have up to 20 modules or more that the client can use at any time. And if I go on loading screen after screen, my application can ocuppy 500MB and more.

The script that I use to load and unload modules is:

```
public function createModule(modulo:String):void {
                if(moduleLoader != null){
                    moduleLoader.unloadModule();
                    //moduleLoader.url = null;
                    moduleLoader.url = "com/oss/facturable/components/" + modulo + "?version=" + model.configXML.versionApp;    
                    moduleLoader.loadModule();
                }       
            }
            private function errorHandler(e:ModuleEvent):void {
                Alert.show("No se ha podido cargar el modulo. Contacte al departamento técnico.");
            }
```

The Container in which the module is loaded:

```
<s:BorderContainer width="98%" height="98%" includeIn="mainState" styleName="bcModuleLoader" top="100">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
                    </s:layout>
                    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
                        <s:Group>
                            <mx:ModuleLoader id="moduleLoader" error="errorHandler(event)" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top" creationComplete="createModule('bandejaEntrada.swf')"/>              
                        </s:Group>
                    </s:Scroller>
 </s:BorderContainer>
```

The createModule function is called whenever I click on a menu option that I think is irrelevant to post here. All in all, this is everything I have for now to make it work and leak :S

This is the official unloadModule function, I thought, by the looks of it, that the memory should be well allocated with this thing, I mean, look! It removes all the eventListeners and child objects. How come my memory stays the same when unloading, and loads more memory on top of it when I open a new module?! Augh!

```
public function unloadModule():void
    {
        if (child)
        {
            removeChild(child);
            child = null;
        }

        if (module)
        {
            module.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.PROGRESS,
                                       moduleProgressHandler);
            module.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.SETUP, moduleSetupHandler);
            module.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, moduleReadyHandler);
            module.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, moduleErrorHandler);

            module.unload();
            module.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, moduleUnloadHandler);
            module = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure each module's children components also have their `eventListeners` removed. I don't suppose any of these modules have `AdvancedDataGrids` with `HierarchicalData` do they?

Comment: Yes, they all have Advanced Datagrids. Some modules have popups which leak too, but I don't need to open them for the app to leak data when navigating different modules.

Comment: Do those AdvancedDataGrids use `HierarchicalData`? I ran into a similar issue where my `AdvancedDataGrids` were causing memory leaks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by HierarchicalData, sorry :S. The DataGrids are written in every Module as traditional mxml, and are assigned dataProviders as arrayCollections from result handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://rocketwidget.com/advanceddatagrid-with-hierarchicaldata-causing-memory-leaks/):

When using `HierachicalData` with an `AdvancedDataGrid`, the control keeps track of hierarchical and grouped data by using the `IHierarchicalCollectionView` interface. The interface has an `openNodes` property contains an Array of objects that represent the nodes of the data provider that are currently open in the AdvancedDataGrid.

If you replace the data provider with a new data provider, the `AdvancedDataGrid` control does not clear the `openNodes` property. Because the `openNodes` property contains references to objects in the old data provider, the objects cannot be removed from memory by garbage collection.  To ensure that the old data provider can be removed from memory, use an event handler to clear the `openNodes` property when you replace the data provider.

Add an event listener to the data provider’s `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` event to clear the openNodes property.

```
// Handle the colectionChange event.
private function removeOpenNodes(event:CollectionEvent):void 
{
  if(event.kind == CollectionEventKind.RESET)
    IHierarchicalCollectionView(adg.dataProvider).openNodes = {};
}
```

Comment: Ok this is gonna sound embarassing, but I don't know where to add that event listener in the CollectionEvent class. Or am I completely lost?

Comment: @overmann No worries. :) Check out http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/897/cpsid_89785.html for a quick example.

Comment: Wait. There's a problem here, my dg.dataProvider object is not recognized as IHierarchicalCollectionView.

Comment: @overmann Are you displaying your data with collapsible groups or in a tree-like format? If you're just showing the data in a traditional single row format, it probably doesn't use a `IHierachicalCollectionView` because there are no nodes to keep track of.

Comment: @overmann Then I would just try to make sure that all of your module's child component's eventListeners have also been removed. If any eventListeners are still present it will keep the component in memory.

Comment: Aren't there other components I should nullify besides removing listeners? Don't you know any good practices about this?

Comment: @overmann To my knowledge, Flex's garbage collection is pretty good about getting rid of components that are no longer needed without having to manually destroy/dispose of them. It may take a few iterations for the garbage collection routine to get to it (it doesn't automatically grab everything that needs to be collected in a single pass. It could take multiple passes). As for best practices, the best practice I can recommend is making sure any eventListeners you create are also destroyed. Those are the usually the things that keep a component in memory.

Comment: Should I take as an eventListener any function that receives an object type "event" or only those "object.addEventlistener()" calls?

Comment: I believe only the ones you create specifically using `addEventListener()`.

Comment: That's what I find weird, you see, I can't imagine how that causes the memory hog because those are only activated for popups, which are presented when a button is pressed, how can this be a problem when a module loads and closes when no popups have been activated?

Comment: @overmann Have you checked to see if those popup objects still have an eventListener as you unload their parent module?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flex 4.5, try to use `<s:ModuleLoader/>` instead.
More details  : [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7ffd.html)

Comment: I'm using Flex 4, and now it's too late to swtich, the proyect is go, and there are clients using it already. I'm currently using the <mx:ModuleLoader/>